# How to change the bitmap image when uninstalling the NSIS installer

Tags: nsis

How to change the bitmap image when uninstalling the NSIS installer?

Because here I didn't find any ID.

When installing the NSIS installer, I changed the bitmap image of the welcome screen using the below code:

```
!define MUI_WELCOMEFINISHPAGE_BITMAP "\NULLSOFT\src\Bitmaps\uninstwiz.bmp"
```

Similarly please suggest me how to change the bitmap image when uninstalling the software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
!define MUI_UNWELCOMEFINISHPAGE_BITMAP "c:\myfiles\uninstwiz.bmp"
!include MUI2.nsh
...
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_WELCOME
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_CONFIRM
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_FINISH
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"
```